# BookShelf orm MySQL how to select column1-column2 as alias

Tags: mysql, knex.js, bookshelf.js

In a raw MySQL query, I have something like this:

```
Select total_sales - over_head_costs As net_sales from departments;
```

How can I realize the same thing with BookShelf /knex query? Ideally not using knex.raw.

My attempt involves following:

```
let Department = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'departments',
  idAttribute: 'department_id',
},{
  getDepartments: function(){
    return this.fetchAll({columns: ['department_id', 'department_name', 'over_head_costs', 'total_sales - over_head_costs AS net_sales']})
    .then(models=>models.toJSON());
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bookshelf does not have this feature but it brings a plugin for that: [Virtuals](https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/wiki/Plugin:-Virtuals)
. No need to install anything, you just load it right after loading Bookshelf using `bookshelf.plugin('virtuals')`.

Your model should then look like:

```
const Department = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'departments',
  idAttribute: 'department_id',
  virtuals: {
    net_sales: function() {
        return this.get('total_sales') - this.get('over_head_costs');
    }
  }
},{
  getDepartments: function(){
    return this.fetchAll({columns: ['department_id', 'department_name', 'over_head_costs', 'net_sales']})
    .then(models=>models.toJSON());
  },
});
```

Comment: would you elaborate on how to "load it right after loading Bookshelf"? 
I have Bookshelf like this `const Bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);
Bookshelf.plugin('virtuals');
module.exports = Bookshelf;`

And in a separate file, I import the config. `const bookshelf = require('../knex_config.js');`

But i am still getting the same error.

Comment: You're doing it right. That is exactly what I mean by "right after". What error are you getting?

Comment: I think still you are not able to select `net_sales` as a column. you can use model.get('net_sales'), but not with a column header.

Comment: Yeah, maybe a `fetch()` limitation on its `columns` parameter. But more likely something that could be improved on the virtuals plugin. I'll give it a look later.